# How to get images from bing web search apiv7 in my flutter application

Tags: image, api, dart, flutter

How can I use Bing web search Apiv7 to get photos in my flutter application?

I got the API and end points from the official site but I was not able to get JSON file to call it in item builder child.

Example-child: `new Image.network('${data['value']['webSearchUrl']}'`

I don't know what to put in this child and where to put the API key...

```
class _PageOneState extends State<PageOne> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: new FutureBuilder(
        future: getPics(),
          builder: (context, snapShot){
          Map data = snapShot.data;
          if(snapShot.hasError){
            print(snapShot.error);
            return Text('Failed to get data from server',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red,
              fontSize: 22.0),);
          }else if(snapShot.hasData){
            return new Center(
              child: new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                  return new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[

                      new Container(
                        child: new InkWell(
                          onTap: (){},
                          child: new Image.network(
                            '${data['value']['webSearchUrl']}'
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      new Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0)),
                    ],
                  );
                  }),
            );

          }
          else if(!snapShot.hasData){
            return new Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          }
          }
      ),

    );
and below the code -


Future<Map> getPics() async{
  String url =
  'https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v7.0/images';
  http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`webSearchUrl` is pointing to a web page with search results, that's why it's not working inside `Image.network()`. Try to change it to `contentUrl` for the full image ur; from third party web or `thumbnailUrl` for the bing hosted small thumbnail url.